# APNS not working with Command Prompt

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, windows-server-2008-r2, apns-php

I use a simple php script to send a push notification from my server to my iPhone (see below). I have already imported the certificates. If I open/**execute** this php-file with **browser** my iPhone receives the Notification and I receive a **positive response** from APNS.

Now, I am trying to execute the same php-file with the **Command Prompt** of my server by using this statement:

```
php -f C:/inetpub/wwwroot/pushNotification/new.php
```

I receive the same, positive response from APNS as when I execute the php-file with my browser, but my **iPhone never receives** the **push notification**.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Thank You!

Björn

php-file:

```
    <?php       

            $deviceToken ='xxxxx';
            $passphrase = 'mypass';

            $message = "TEST";

            $ctx = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck-pub.pem');
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

            $fp = stream_socket_client(
                'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

            if (!$fp)
                exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

            echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

            $body['aps'] = array(
                'alert' => $message,
                'sound' => 'default'
                );

            $payload = json_encode($body);

            $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

            $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

            if (!$result)
                echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
            else
                echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

            fclose($fp);

?>
```

**Command Prompt response:**

```
Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered
```

Comment: On the `cmd` are you getting one of those messages(i.e: Connected to APNS)??

Comment: Yes. I edit the question so that you can see the cmd output. @Hackerman

Comment: Try executing the command inside the `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/pushNotification/` folder and typing `php -f new.php`(Just for testing)

Comment: Wow. It works @Hackerman . But is there a possibility to make it work like described in my question?

Comment: It seems that there is difference between running `new.php` from the browser(IIS_IUSRS) and from the command line(Actual User)....maybe privileges or something....why do you need to run it that way??...you want to create an Automated Task??

Comment: Yes, I have an automated task which executes file1.php within this file I use shell_ex() to execute new.php. Another possible solution would be to switch the cmd directory in file1.php - how could I do this? @Hackerman

Comment: You can try creating a bat file, like: 
        `@echo off 
        set folder = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pushNotification
        cd %folder%
        start php -f news.php`

Comment: I try an .bat approach and it is not working...can you post the content of your file1.php?

Comment: file1 uses this line of code: exec('php -f C:/inetpub/wwwroot/pushNotification/new.php'); @Hackerman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a `.cmd` file with the following lines(ie: test.cmd):

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pushNotification\
php -f news.php
```

And in your `file1.php`, use this line of code instead:

```
exec('test.cmd');
```

Hope this helps.

> Not tested: You can pass arguments on this way too:

```
exec('test.cmd arg1 arg2');
```

> And in the `.cmd` file

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pushNotification\
php -f news.php %1 %2
```

Comment: Alright, this works fine for me but now I encounter a new problem. In file1 I pass some arguments to the new.php: 
'php -f C:/inetpub/wwwroot/pushNotification/new.php "'.escapeshellarg($arg1).'" "'.escapeshellarg($arg2).'"      "'.escapeshellarg($arg3)
How can I pass those to the cmd file and use them in it? @Hackerman

Comment: Glad to help @Burn, and glad that you find the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you try to execute the php1-file in another php2-file (using exec()), this is the solution **based on Hackerman's hint** that you have to change the directory.

You change the directory of your php2 process using:

```
chdir('php1_directory_path');
```

after that you can execute your php1-file as if php2 would be running in php1's directory by using:

```
exec('php -f php1.php')
```

This solution has the advantage that you still can pass arguments to php1:

```
exec('php -f *php1.php* "'.escapeshellarg(arg1).'" "'.escapeshellarg(arg2))
```